# Qt Build 5.9.1 Static with OCI Driver

Tags: c++, qt, static, oracle-call-interface

I want to build Qt 5.9.1 in static with the support of OCI driver.

I configure it with :

```
-static -debug-and-release -platform win32-g++ -prefix D:\Qt\5.9.1\5.9.1\Static -opensource -confirm-license -c++std c++14 -nomake examples -skip qtdoc -skip wayland -skip purchasing -skip serialbus -skip qtserialport -skip script -skip scxml -skip speech -skip location -no-opengl -no-angle -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -no-libjpeg -qt-freetype -sql-oci "OCI_INCDIR=D:\app\013798432\product\11.2.0\client_1\oci\include" "OCI_LIBDIR=D:\app\013798432\product\11.2.0\client_1\oci\lib\msvc" "OCI_LIBS=-loci -lociw32 -loraocci11"
```

But I have the following error :

```
ERROR: Feature 'sql-oci' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.oci' failed.
```

I also add the INCLUDE path and LIB path in the system environment

How can I do to compil Qt statically with the OCI support ?

Comment: I configure for mysql and psql via `-sql-psql -sql-mysql MYSQL_INCDIR=E:\msys64\mingw64\include\mariadb MYSQL_LIBDIR=E:\msys64\mingw64\lib MYSQL_LIBS="-l mysqlclient" -L E:\msys64\mingw64\lib` and everything is configured property. Maybe you need to remove those `""`. The build fails nonetheless, to be honest I haven't had a successful static Qt build since 5.8 came out.

Comment: I have try this : `-sql-oci OCI_INCDIR=D:\app\013798432\product\11.2.0\client_1\oci\include OCI_LIBDIR=D:\app\013798432\product\11.2.0\client_1\oci\lib\msvc OCI_LIBS="-loci -lociw32 -loraocci11"` same result :/